# Volume icon dissapeared

Tags: kde, plasma

Looking for fixing the heavy backsound ( I have to use bluetooth for audio to avoid that noise), the volume icon dissapeared.
Interestingly enough, if I start session with Wayland or Cinammon, the icon is there, but I prefer to use Plasma KDE.
ah, there is no audio or sound tab in settings either
Any Help? thank you very much

Comment: You need to give us at least a little information … what version of Ubuntu, maybe what’s your hardware, what did you do that got rid of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

via https://www.linuxquestions.org/question ... 175659386/

I found new solution: in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
I wrote:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,2
```

And restarted session